# Enabling App Attest capability for live app

Tags: ios, firebase-app-check

I have an app live on the App Store, if I add App Attest capability now will it be applicable to existing users who are using my iOS app?

I have made all the changes required while building the app and also configured Firebase for the same but when I am enforcing the APP CHECK in Firebase my iOS users are not able to use the app. Then I figured out that in iOS Developer setting under Identifier APP ATTEST capability is not enabled. So if I enable it now, what will happen to users who are already using my app?

[image: While enabling the capability this popup appears1]